# send an image to a form as uploaded file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had a code that looks like this https://cloth.ardive.id/Tshirt/index.html

I want to send the canvas as an image to a form where user need to fill some addon information (name, category) and in this form image from page before is have been displayed and user doesnt need to upload an image anymore. So when they submit the form, submited form is contains their filled information data with the image

because i want to send the canvas that wasnt an image, so we need to generates the canvas into image, then send it to the form

this is the code to save the image that have been already generated from the canvas to users desktop
the code is on canvas2image.js

```js
    // sends the generated file to the client
     var saveFile = function(strData) {
      document.location.href = strData;
     }
    
     var makeDataURI = function(strData, strMime) {
      return "data:" + strMime + ";base64," + strData;
     }
    
     // generates a <img> object containing the imagedata
     var makeImageObject = function(strSource) {
      var oImgElement = document.createElement("img");
      oImgElement.src = strSource;
      return oImgElement;
     }
    
     var scaleCanvas = function(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight) {
      if (iWidth && iHeight) {
       var oSaveCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
       oSaveCanvas.width = iWidth;
       oSaveCanvas.height = iHeight;
       oSaveCanvas.style.width = iWidth+"px";
       oSaveCanvas.style.height = iHeight+"px";
    
       var oSaveCtx = oSaveCanvas.getContext("2d");
    
       oSaveCtx.drawImage(oCanvas, 0, 0, oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
       return oSaveCanvas;
      }
      return oCanvas;
     }
    
     return {
    
      saveAsPNG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
       if (!bHasDataURL) {
        return false;
       }
       var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
       var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       if (bReturnImg) {
        return makeImageObject(strData);
       } else {
        saveFile(strData.replace("image/png", strDownloadMime));
       }
       return true;
      }
```

this is another js to classed the function

```js
//export options
   $('.exportas').click(function(){
        // get type to export
        var to = $(this).data('type');
       // alert(to);
       // get our canvas
       var oCanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");  
    // support variable
    var bRes = false;
        if(to == 'png'){
            // export to png 
            bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
        }
        if(to == 'jpg'){
            // maybe in some old browsers it works only on Firefox
            bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas);
        }if(to == 'bmp'){
            Res = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas);
        }
        // if browser doesn't support mimetype alert user
        if (!bRes) {
            alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
            return false;
        }
```

and on index.html, its look like this

```html
<!-- export option (png, jpg, bmp) -->
                                <li>
                                    <div class="btn-group dropup">

                                      <a class="dropdown-toggle export btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                        Export
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                      </a>

                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='png'>PNG</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='jpg'>JPG</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='bmp'>BMP</a>
                                        </li>
```

so what i wanna ask you is, how to make a code to send the image to form (form is on another pages) with details i have been mentioned above. thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code (not a link to a site).  Also, please clarify your problem by telling us what result you are currently getting, and what result you want to get.

Comment: i dont know the code really, im beginner anyway.

Comment: you could view the code on developer mode

Comment: Do You want to display the selected image file as preview to the button and then on clicking the button do you want to upload the image?

Comment: i only need to send image data to a form page. after click the submit button, the image they have been generates is uploaded and displayed on the form (so user doesnt need to upload image anymore, only need to complate the form). @Blip

Answer (score 0):

so the image is already uploaded you just have to save it right?`

```
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'upload';   //2

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $new_folder . $ds;  //4

$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
```

i think you can try something like this in php so this is the upload.php. You have to implement the upload php to your index.html